# use lookandfeel exclude some GUI object

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtree, look-and-feel

I find some lookandfeel plugin and I want to use it in my application,
LAF work entire GUI object, but I have some custom GUI object,for example i custom the JCheckbox and JTree, if I use the lookandfeel then my customize will be cover, I don't know how to show them when use LAF.

Comment: Write compatible UI delegates for you custom components which conform to the desired look and feels requirements